# Immutable dictionary, only use as a key for another dictionary

Tags: python

I had the need to implement a hashable dict so I could use a dictionary as a key for another dictionary.

A few months ago I used this implementation: [Python hashable dicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151658/python-hashable-dicts)

However I got a notice from a colleague saying 'it is not really immutable, thus it is not safe. You can use it, but it does make me feel like a sad Panda'.

So I started looking around to create one that is immutable. I have no need to compare the 'key-dict' to another 'key-dict'. Its only use is as a key for another dictionary.

I have come up with the following:

```
class HashableDict(dict):
    """Hashable dict that can be used as a key in other dictionaries"""

    def __new__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # create a new local dict, that will be used by the HashableDictBase closure class
        immutableDict = dict(*args, **kwargs)

        class HashableDictBase(object):
            """Hashable dict that can be used as a key in other dictionaries. This is now immutable"""

            def __key(self):
                """Return a tuple of the current keys"""
                return tuple((k, immutableDict[k]) for k in sorted(immutableDict))

            def __hash__(self):
                """Return a hash of __key"""
                return hash(self.__key())

            def __eq__(self, other):
                """Compare two __keys"""
                return self.__key() == other.__key() # pylint: disable-msg=W0212

            def __repr__(self):
                """@see: dict.__repr__"""
                return immutableDict.__repr__()

            def __str__(self):
                """@see: dict.__str__"""
                return immutableDict.__str__()

            def __setattr__(self, *args):
                raise TypeError("can't modify immutable instance")
            __delattr__ = __setattr__

        return HashableDictBase()
```

I used the following to test the functionality:

```
d = {"a" : 1}

a = HashableDict(d)
b = HashableDict({"b" : 2})

print a
d["b"] = 2
print a

c = HashableDict({"a" : 1})

test = {a : "value with a dict as key (key a)",
        b : "value with a dict as key (key b)"}

print test[a]
print test[b]
print test[c]
```

which gives:

> {'a': 1}
>   {'a': 1}
>   value with a dict as key (key a)
>   value with a dict as key (key b)
>   value with a dict as key (key a)

as output

Is this the 'best possible' immutable dictionary that I can use that satisfies my requirements? If not, what would be a better solution?

Comment: A slightly nicer method would be ``tuple(sorted(immutableDict.items()))`` (or ``iteritems()`` pre 3.x). Also, just as a note, I'd go for ``FrozenDict`` as a name given the ``frozenset`` class that exists in Python by default, just for naming consistency - not that it really matters.

Comment: Your colleague may be missing the point of a "consenting adults language" where nothing in pure python code is truly private (in the sense of being enforced).  What your code does is very close to being the intended way to create immutable objects.  Consider the *ImmutableSet* code in Lib/sets.py that was written by Guido van Rossum, Alex Martelli, Greg Wilson and myself.  Does the core developer's code in standard library code make your colleague "feel like a sad Panda"?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you are only using it as a key for another `dict`, you could go for `frozenset(mutabledict.items())`. If you need to access the underlying mappings, you could then use that as the parameter to `dict`.

```
mutabledict = dict(zip('abc', range(3)))
immutable = frozenset(mutabledict.items())
read_frozen = dict(immutable)
read_frozen['a'] # => 1
```

Note that you could also combine this with a class derived from `dict`, and use the `frozenset` as the source of the hash, while disabling `__setitem__`, as suggested in another answer. ([@RaymondHettinger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9997519/21640) for code which does just that).

Comment: I like this - a ``dict`` is inherently orderless, so sorting it then making it a tuple seems a hackish way of ensuring equality by forcing an order - which could break if what you are storing has weird ordering. This way doesn't do that. This way is simpler, cleaner and I would say the best.

Comment: As I said in another answer, unusable and not pythonic. `enum` or [pip package frozendict](https://pypi.org/project/frozendict/) are much better.

Comment: @MarcoSulla Python 3.4 was released on March 16, 2014. That is the first version with enum. This answer is from 2012. `frozendict` was released some 6 months after this answer.,

Answer (score 22):

The *Mapping* abstract base class makes this easy to implement:

```
import collections

class ImmutableDict(collections.Mapping):
    def __init__(self, somedict):
        self._dict = dict(somedict)   # make a copy
        self._hash = None

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._dict[key]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._dict)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._dict)

    def __hash__(self):
        if self._hash is None:
            self._hash = hash(frozenset(self._dict.items()))
        return self._hash

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._dict == other._dict
```

Comment: I like your answer, however it is still not immutable. One can still reach the `ImmutableDict({"a" : 1}).dict` variable and change it. Yes you can make it hidden by `__dict` but then you can still reach it by using `ImmutableDict({"a" : 1})._ImmutableDict__dict`. Thus it is not 'really' immutable ;-)

Comment: also you are missing the `__eq__` method. It is using that one as well. When you change the `.dict` afterwards the self.hash won't be updated which would seem as if it will still use it, but it doesn't use it to compare they keys it seems. It also uses `__eq__`. When I overrid it and compared the `__hash__` methods it did work?

Comment: I've implemented @RaymondHettinger 's solution and packaged it up so that it is `pip install`-able. Check out [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39673094/1490091) for more details.

Comment: If you want to sort collections of dictionaries, you may also want to implement `__cmp__`.

Answer (score 10):

I realize this has already been answered, but [types.MappingProxyType](http://docs.python.org/release/3.3.0/library/types.html#types.MappingProxyType) is an analogous implementation for Python 3.3. Regarding the original question of safety, there is a discussion in [PEP 416 -- Add a frozendict builtin type](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0416/) on why the idea of a `frozendict` was rejected.

Answer (score 9):

In order for your immutable dictionary to be safe, all it needs to do is never change its hash. Why don't you just disable `__setitem__` as follows:

```
class ImmutableDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        raise Exception("Can't touch this")
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(tuple(sorted(self.items())))

a = ImmutableDict({'a':1})
b = {a:1}
print b
print b[a]
a['a'] = 0
```

The output of the script is:

```
{{'a': 1}: 1}
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex.py", line 11, in <module>
    a['a'] = 0
  File "ex.py", line 3, in __setitem__
    raise Exception("Can't touch this")
Exception: Can't touch this
```

Comment: Still not 100% immutable, as `object.__setattr__` can bypass this.

`>>> b = ImmutableDict()
>>> b.__hash__()
3527539
>>> object.__setattr__(b, "items", {"bacon": "eggs"}.items)
>>> b.__hash__()
28501310`

Answer (score 5):

Here is a link to `pip install`-able implementation of [@RaymondHettinger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9997519/21640): https://github.com/pcattori/icicle

Simply `pip install icicle` and you can `from icicle import FrozenDict`!

**Update:** `icicle` has been deprecated in favor of `maps`: https://github.com/pcattori/maps ([documentation](https://maps.readthedocs.io/), [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/maps)).

Answer (score 3):

It appears I am late to post. Not sure if anyone else has come up with ideas. But here is my take on it. The Dict is immutable and hashable. I made it immutable by overriding all the methods, magic and otherwise, with a custom '_readonly' function that raises an Exception. This is done when the object is instantiated. To get around the problem of not being able to apply the values I set the 'hash' under '__new__'. I then I override the '__hash__'function. Thats it!

```
class ImmutableDict(dict):

_HASH = None

def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    ImmutableDict._HASH = hash(frozenset(args[0].items()))
    return super(ImmutableDict, cls).__new__(cls, args)

def __hash__(self):
    return self._HASH

def _readonly(self, *args, **kwards):
    raise TypeError("Cannot modify Immutable Instance")

__delattr__ = __setattr__ = __setitem__ = pop = update = setdefault = clear = popitem = _readonly
```

Test:

> immutabled1 = ImmutableDict({"This": "That", "Cheese": "Blarg"})
>
> dict1 = {immutabled1: "Yay"}
>
> dict1[immutabled1]
>
> "Yay"
>
> dict1
>
> {{'Cheese': 'Blarg', 'This': 'That'}: 'Yay'}

Answer (score 1):

Variation of [Raymond Hettinger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9997519/21640) by wrapping the `self._dict` with `types.MappingProxyType`.

```
class ImmutableDict(collections.Mapping):
    """
    Copies a dict and proxies it via types.MappingProxyType to make it immutable.
    """
    def __init__(self, somedict):
        dictcopy = dict(somedict) # make a copy
        self._dict = MappingProxyType(dictcopy) # lock it
        self._hash = None

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._dict[key]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._dict)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._dict)

    def __hash__(self):
        if self._hash is None:
            self._hash = hash(frozenset(self._dict.items()))
        return self._hash

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._dict == other._dict

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self._dict)
```

Comment: I think it's useless to use `MappingProxyType`. `_dict` is signaled as protected attribute, so if you want to access or mutate it, you can do it for inspection, or simply it's your fault.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an enum:

```
import enum

KeyDict1 = enum.Enum('KeyDict1', {'InnerDictKey1':'bla', 'InnerDictKey2 ':2})

d = { KeyDict1: 'whatever', KeyDict2: 1, ...}
```

You can access the enums like you would a dictionary:

```
KeyDict1['InnerDictKey2'].value  # This is 2
```

You can iterate over the names, and get their values... It does everything you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using https://github.com/Lightricks/freeze

It provides recursively immutable and hashable dictionaries

```py
from freeze import FDict

a_mutable_dict = {
    "list": [1, 2],
    "set": {3, 4},
}

a_frozen_dict = FDict(a_mutable_dict)

print(a_frozen_dict)
print(hash(a_frozen_dict))

# FDict: {'list': FList: (1, 2), 'set': FSet: {3, 4}}
# -4855611361973338606
```