# Hashing an immutable dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, hash, immutability, python-3.2

**Short version:** What's the best hashing  algorithm for a multiset implemented as a dictionary of unordered items?

I'm trying to hash an immutable multiset (which is a bag or multiset in other languages: like a mathematical set except that it can hold more than one of each element) implemented as a dictionary. I've created a subclass of the standard library class `collections.Counter`, similar to the advice here: [Python hashable dicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151658/python-hashable-dicts), which recommends a hash function like so:

```python
class FrozenCounter(collections.Counter):
    # ...
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(tuple(sorted(self.items())))
```

Creating the full tuple of items takes up a lot of memory (relative to, say, using a generator) and hashing will occur in an extremely memory intensive part of my application. More importantly, my dictionary keys (multiset elements) probably won't be order-able.

I'm thinking of using this algorithm:

```python
def __hash__(self):
    return functools.reduce(lambda a, b: a ^ b, self.items(), 0)
```

I figure using bitwise XOR means **order doesn't matter for the hash value unlike in the hashing of a tuple?** I suppose I could semi-implement the Python tuple-hashing alogrithm on the unordered stream of tuples of my data. See https://github.com/jonashaag/cpython/blob/master/Include/tupleobject.h (search in the page for the word 'hash') -- but I barely know enough C to read it.

**Thoughts? Suggestions? Thanks.**

---

(*If you're wondering why I'm messing around with trying to hash a multiset:* The input data for my problem are sets of multisets, and within each set of multisets, each multiset must be unique. I'm working on a deadline and I'm not an experienced coder, so I wanted to avoid inventing new algorithms where possible. It seems like the most Pythonic way to make sure I have unique of a bunch of things is to put them in a `set()`, but the things must be hashable.)

---

## What I've gathered from the comments

Both @marcin and @senderle gave pretty much the same answer: use `hash(frozenset(self.items()))`. This makes sense because [`items()` "views" are set-like](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects). @marcin was first but I gave the check mark to @senderle because of the good research on the big-O running times for different solutions. @marcin also reminds me to [include an `__eq__` method](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) -- but the one inherited from `dict` will work just fine. This is how I'm implementing everything -- further comments and suggestions based on this code are welcome:

```python
class FrozenCounter(collections.Counter):
    # Edit: A previous version of this code included a __slots__ definition.
    # But, from the Python documentation: "When inheriting from a class without
    # __slots__, the __dict__ attribute of that class will always be accessible,
    # so a __slots__ definition in the subclass is meaningless."
    # http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html#notes-on-using-slots
    # ...
    def __hash__(self):
        "Implements hash(self) -> int"
        if not hasattr(self, '_hash'):
            self._hash = hash(frozenset(self.items()))
        return self._hash
```

Comment: Any object that is hashable is orderable. If it's hashable then it always produces the same hash, so sort on the hash.

Comment: Are you _sure_ making the `tuple` takes a lot of memory? It's just a "pointer" to each item in the dict, not a copy of it, that gets created.

Comment: Check out http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~tijmen/programming/immutableDictionaries.html

Comment: +1 for a very comprehensive update to the question, as well as providing a final implementation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since the dictionary is immutable, you can create the hash when the dictionary is created and return it directly. My suggestion would be to create a [`frozenset`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) from `items` (in 3+; `iteritems` in 2.7), hash it, and store the hash.

To provide an explicit example:

```
>>>> frozenset(Counter([1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4]).iteritems())
frozenset([(3, 2), (1, 3), (4, 1), (2, 1)])
>>>> hash(frozenset(Counter([1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4]).iteritems()))
-3071743570178645657
>>>> hash(frozenset(Counter([1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4]).iteritems()))
-6559486438209652990
```

To clarify why I prefer a `frozenset` to a tuple of sorted items: a `frozenset` doesn't have to sort the items, and so the initial hash completes in O(n) time rather than O(n log n) time. This can be seen from the [`frozenset_hash`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5fd1ac1c9474/Objects/setobject.c#l766) and [`set_next`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5fd1ac1c9474/Objects/setobject.c#l531) implementations.

See also this [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20931478) from Raymond Hettinger describing his implementation of the `frozenset` hash function. There he explicitly explains how the hash function avoids having to sort values to get a stable, order insensitive value.

Comment: So you're saying that `hash(frozenset(myfrozendict.iteritems()))` is faster than `hash(myfrozendict.iteritems())`, for little and huge `myfrozendict`s?

Comment: @MarcoSulla no, I'm saying it should be faster (for large objects) than `hash(tuple(sorted(self.items())))`. I do not believe `hash(myfrozendict.iteritems())` gives a valid hash: it's not guaranteed to be the same for two identical `myfrozendict`s. This is because the iteration order of `iteritems` can depend on things like insertion order. (Hence the `sort` requirement.)

Comment: Ok... but I have some doubts. Do you know where I can find the implementation of `hash()` for `dict`?

Comment: @MarcoSulla Not sure I understand. Dicts aren't hashable!

Comment: Sorrry, I mean `__hash__`

Comment: @MarcoSulla I'm saying it doesn't have one. Run `{}.__hash__()` in a Python console and see what happens.

Comment: .................well, yes, obviously it can't be hashed, is a mutable type....... sorry for the mistake. But in this case, [py docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) are wrong.

Comment: @MarcoSulla Hmm... I don't see an error there either, though perhaps there's something phrased in a confusing way?

Comment: Excuse me, it's written `dict. __hash__ etc` and I read `dict.__hash__ etc`

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered `hash(sorted(hash(x) for x in self.items()))`? That way, you are only sorting integers, and don't have to build a list.

You could also xor the element hashes together, but frankly I don't how well that would work (would you have a lot of collisions?). Speaking of collisions, don't you have to implement the `__eq__` method?

Alternatively, similar to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9997296/21640), `hash(frozenset(self.items()))`.

Comment: List is not hashable. Should be `hash(tuple(sorted(...`