# Make a list of ints hashable in python

Tags: python, hash

I have a lists of integers that I would like to use as keys in python dictionaries.  I'm caching results from a function(s) that takes a list of ints as input.  My current solution:

```
list_of_ints = [1,20,3,4]
key = str(sorted(list_of_ints))[1:-1].replace(' ','')
```

which generates the key '1,3,4,20'.  Seems like there should be a faster/prettier/more-pythonic way to do this.

Comment: If the lists don't have duplicate elements, you can [use `frozenset` keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28566797/is-it-safe-to-use-frozen-set-as-dict-key).

Comment: Duplicate of [Why can't I use a list as a dict key in python? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257588/why-cant-i-use-a-list-as-a-dict-key-in-python) -- except that in this case you like the "list" to be unordered, so a frozen set is more suited.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just use a tuple as a key. Tuples are immutable and hashable, so they're useful as dictionary keys.

```
list_of_ints = [1, 20, 3, 4]
# tuple(list_of_ints) == (1, 20, 3, 4)

some_dict = {tuple(list_of_ints): "some value", ...}
```

Notably they DO care about order, so `[1, 20, 3, 4]` won't produce the same value as `[1, 3, 20, 4]`

You could even create a container that does this for you.

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        key = tuple(sorted(key))
        return super().__getitem__(key)
    # similar for pop, get, setdefault, update....

>>> d = MyDict()
>>> d[1,2,3] = 4
>>> d[3,2,1]
4
```

Don't try to serialize it yourself. If you do, don't use string manipulation -- it's too ugly. If you are sincerely memory starved or you have hundreds of thousands of these records, you could save insignificant space by serializing like:

```
def my_serialize(key_nums: list):
    key_nums = sorted(key_nums)
    base = max(key_nums)
    sum_ = 0
    for power, num in enumerate(key_nums):
        sum_ += base**power * num
    return sum_
```

which should give you a unique (incredibly large!) integer to store that will be smaller in memory than the tuple. Don't do this if you can avoid it -- it's very opaque.

---

In the comments you mention you will not have duplicate values in the key, so `frozenset` is definitely what you're looking for.

```
d = {}
list_of_ints = [1, 20, 3, 4]
d[frozenset(list_of_ints)] = "some value"
```

[`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) objects are immutable hashable `set`-like objects. They are order-agnostic and ignore duplicates.

Comment: I guess I should add that the order of the ints doesn't matter, so I think I still want the sorted in there, but:

    key=tuple(sorted(list_of_ints))

is a lot prettier.

Comment: @I.P.Freeley are there always 4 ints?

Comment: No, variable length.

Comment: The order of the function parameters doesn't matter? How strange.

Comment: It's pretty common - e.g. sum(), multiply()

Comment: The "container" that is order agnostic would probably be better if implemented as a `frozenset(...)` rather than `tuple(sorted(...))`.  With that said, your container is still missing a bunch of methods -- `.pop`, `.get`, `.setdefault` and probably others that I'm not remembering at the moment. . .

Comment: @mgilson fair point, but I don't feel like hacking away a ton of code so I'll just write a note in the answer.

Comment: @mgilson `frozenset` only works if `(1, 2, 3)` is identical to `(1, 2, 3, 3)` which seems like a stretch

Comment: @AdamSmith -- Ahh, that's a good point.  I didn't think of that.  *sigh* N-LogN it is then . . .

Comment: Yes, I should not have repeat values, so I think `frozenset` is the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You also can create hashable list.

```
from collections import Iterable

class hash_list(list): 
    def __init__(self, *args): 
        if len(args) == 1 and isinstance(args[0], Iterable): 
            args = args[0] 
        super().__init__(args) 
         
    def __hash__(self): 
        return hash(e for e in self)
```

And now this works:

```
hash(hash_list(1, 2, 3))
```

or

```
hash(hash_list([1, 2, 3]))
```

Comment: Might be a stupid question but If you are changing the type to a generator why not just use a tuple?

Comment: @SujalSingh sometimes you need mutable and at the same time hashable sequence.