# unhashable type: 'list' - what went wrong?

Tags: python

hello i am required to write a function that returns the highest level of competence attainable in all the years available in the data, given a particular school and grade. Given a row, if the data for any of the level competence is missing, ignore the given row. The highest level of competence is attained if the number for that particular level is non-zero. i am supposed to return the result as a dictionary where the key is the year and the value is the highest level.
but the code below gives me the error unhashable type: 'list'. may i know where i went wrong in my code? thank you!

```
def highest_level(filename, school, grade):
  data = read_csv(filename)
  header = data[0]
  length = len(header)
  length1 = len(data)
  year = data[2]
  col = ''
  for i in range(length):
    if header[i] == str(school):
      for j in range(1, length1):
        if data[j][2] == str(year):
          col = col + [(float(data[j][i]))]
    else:
      continue
  col1 = col
  number = filter(lambda row: row[i] == str(school), data)
  if data[8] != '':
    return {year: 4}
  else:
    return None


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hannan/Downloads/challenge6_template.py", line 36, in <module>
    print(highest_level("Math.csv", "A.C.E. ACADEMY FOR SCHOLARS AT THE GERALDINE FERRARO CAMPUS", 3))
  File "/Users/hannan/Downloads/challenge6_template.py", line 30, in highest_level
    return {year: 4}
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Always include the complete error traceback in your question: we don't want to try and guess what part of the code raised this error.

Comment: Apparently, `year` is a list, and a list can't be used as a dictionary key, as it isn't hashable. Check the value of `year` in your code.

Comment: The code shown seems to have a type error related to `col`, but that is unrelated to the error described. The described error is more likely from extracting `year` from `data` instead of `header`, or something like that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make a list of ints hashable in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35004882/make-a-list-of-ints-hashable-in-python)

Comment: @ThierryLathuille i have edited my code for the year to be returned as a string instead. thanks for helping!! :)