# Unmutable dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am seeking a way to store (convert) my existing dict into a non mutable entity. Is there any python builtin I can use here?

If I were using a set, I could use a frozenset, and if in case if I was using a list, I could've converted it into a tuple, but there seems to be no such similar option for the dict.

Ultimately, I need to convert the dicts in to unmutable dicts, so that I can (possibly hash them and thus) store them in a set.

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703599/what-would-be-a-frozen-dict

Comment: Also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997176/immutable-dictionary-only-use-as-a-key-for-another-dictionary)