# A workaround for Python's missing frozen-dict type?

Tags: python, dictionary, immutability

In Python, when you want to use lists as keys of some dictionary, you can turn them into tuples, which are immutable and hence are hashable.

```
>>> a = {}
>>> a[tuple(list_1)] = some_value
>>> a[tuple(list_2)] = some_other_value
```

The same happens when you want to use **set** objects as keys of some dictionary - you can build a **frozenset**, that is again immutable and hence is hashable.

```
>>> a = {}
>>> a[frozenset(set_1)] = some_value
>>> a[frozenset(set_2)] = some_other_value
```

But it seems that for dictionary there is no equivalent.

A first idea I thought about (and found it bad finally), is to use `str(some_dict)` as a key. But, dictionaries always use different hash functions (which affects the order of elements), so strings of equal dictionaries may be different.

Is there any workaround known as a good practice, or does anyone have other ideas how to use dictionary-like objects as keys of other dictionaries?

Comment: You could call `str()` on a `collections.OrderedDict`?

Comment: @SimeonVisser OrderedDict: unless you consider the order the elements were added to be part of the value of the dict, you may be surprised at the behaviour you get - I used to imagine OrderedDict was a tree map, ordered by key, but alas (for this use case) not.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

### EDIT:

Starting from Python 3.6, dictionaries preserve the insertion order. Therefore, the workaround would vary depending on the used Python version.

**For Python < 3.6 (Dictionaries do not preserve insertion order)** - use **frozenset**, so that two sets are equal even if order is different:

```
>>> a = {'key1' : 'val1', 'key2' : 'val2'}
>>> b = frozenset(a.items())
>>> frozenset_restored_to_dict = dict(b)
>>> frozenset_restored_to_dict
{'key2': 'val2', 'key1': 'val1'}
```

**Otherwise (Dictionaries preserve insertion order)**, use **tuple**. This way, the dictionary can be restored while preserving the order of items, yet, **tuples with same items ordered differently will not be equal**. A workaround for it would be passing the tuples to a frozenset constructor each time before a comparison is made.

```
>>> a = {'key1' : 'val1', 'key2' : 'val2'}
>>> b = tuple(a.items())
>>> tuple_restored_to_dict = dict(b)
>>> tuple_restored_to_dict
{'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}
```

As can be seen in the code, `b` is a tuple, or a frozenset. Either are immutable and hashable, and can be totally restored to be a regular dictionary like `a`.

Comment: Note that this requires the dict values to be hashable as well as the keys.

Comment: This would lose the best property of `dict` objects, though, namely that lookups by key can be achieved in constant time.

Comment: @SomethingSomething, as pointed out by BrentBam, won't work with more complicated examples, eg `{'a':[1,2],'b':{'c':[3,4,5],('d','e'):"blah"}}`. You'd have to   recursively freeze any non-hashable values including nested dicts, and keep track of type to unfreeze, if there are distinct types that map to the same set.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [ordered dict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) or look on these answers:

- [What would a "frozen dict" be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703599/what-would-a-frozen-dict-be)
- [Immutable dictionary, only use as a key for another dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997176/immutable-dictionary-only-use-as-a-key-for-another-dictionary)
- [How to create an immutable dictionary in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014262/how-to-create-an-immutable-dictionary-in-python)

and there is even a package on PyPI: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/frozendict

You can also simply convert dict to tuples(`sorted(your_dict.items())`) and then use as a hash.

UPD: as mentioned in comments, OrderedDict is unhashable. My bad, it is really should not be hashable since it is mutable.

Comment: `OrderedDict`s are also not hashable.

Comment: note that it's possible to use `frozenset` instead of tuple of sorted