# Is there any way how to make set operators work with sets, in which objects are stored?

Tags: python, object, set

I'm trying to find a way how to compare objects in sets to make & operator work properly on them.

I was trying to find source codes to Set function `intersect()`, but hopelessly. I have tried to overload the equals operator, but when I added `__eq__()` function into the class definition, the Person objects became unhashable.

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, dictionary):
        self.dictionary = dictionary

def foo1():
    first_set.add(Person({"age" : 20}))

def foo2():
    second_set.add(Person({"age" : 20}))

first_set = set()
second_set = set()

foo1()
foo2()

print(first_set)
print(second_set)
print(first_set & second_set)  # I'd like to get non-empty intersection here
```

I thought it could work somehow with `__eq__()` overloading, but it's not possible.

Comment: Use ABC Set class and override `__eq__` method, https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your classes collection safe like this, you need to override both `__eq__` and `__hash__` - see https://hynek.me/articles/hashes-and-equality/ and [Recommended way to implement __eq__ and __hash__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45164691/recommended-way-to-implement-eq-and-hash).

Comment: Of course, dictionaries (being mutable) aren't safely hashable.

Comment: True - you'd need some kind of [frozendict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39440190/a-workaround-for-pythons-missing-frozen-dict-type).