# Python reversed mapping / dictionary with unhashable type?

Tags: python

I've created a dictionary like

```
d = {1: {"a":1, "b":2}, 2: {"a":1, "b":2}}
```

I'm looping through objects to create dictionaries like the above.

I also want to create a reverse of the above dictionary while I loop, it should look like

```
d2 = {{"a":1, "b":2}: 1, {"a":1, "b":2}: 2}
```

I know that the dictionary is an unhashable type, but at the same time I want the ability to reverse look up values without looping through the dictionary.

Is there some way to do this in python?

Comment: What is the mapping for `{"a":1, "b":2}`, 1 or 2? See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151658/python-hashable-dicts) on making dicts hashable.

Comment: for reverse: `d2 = {d[k]:k for k in d}`.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: There are other things to be considered. See my answer

Comment: @Abhijit Yes thats why I posted comment and answer. and vote you

Comment: A namedtuple kinda-sorta works like a frozendict

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I also want to create a reverse of the above dictionary while I loop,
>   it should look like

1. No, you can't. All keys to a dictionary should be hash-able and a dictionary is not hash-able
2. Key's cannot have duplicate entries

> Is there some way to do this in python?

Unless you wan't the key's to be dictionary, you can convert to some other data structure. May be `frozenset of item lists`?

If you need duplicate keys, use `frozenset of item lists` with [MultiMap 1.0.3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MultiMap)

And google returned me an implementation of [frozen dict](http://bob.ippoli.to/archives/2005/03/04/frozendict/), you can use it with [MultiMap 1.0.3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MultiMap)