# Convert a BaseClass object into a SubClass object idiomatically?

Tags: python, inheritance, subclass, class-method

There is a base class `Base` and a subclass `Special`.

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def greet(self):
        return 'Hello %s' % self.name

class Special(Base):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Special, self).__init__(name)
    def rhyme(self):
        return 'Hi %s! How are you? Fine, thanks. What about you?' % self.name
```

How can I turn an instance of `Base` into an instance `Special`? Currently I have a `classmethod` defined on `Special` that just reassignes `__dict__`:

```
class Special(Base):
    ...
    @classmethod
    def from_base(cls, baseobj):
        special = Special()
        special.__dict__ = baseobj.__dict__
        return special
```

Is this idiomatic? If not what would be?

P.S. An example scenario: The base class is some default implementation. In the wild, you'll likely find objects of the base class. Now in some project, the base class has been subclasses and special methods have been added to the subclass. Now you mostly still work with base class objects, but from time to time you'll want to "upgrade" to the special class, because you'll need access to some methods.

Comment: Why is it not possible to instantiate or force use of `Special`?

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve this by defining an alternate constructor and reassigning the instance's `__class__` attribute.

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def greet(self):
        return 'Hello %s' % self.name

    @classmethod
    def alt_constructor(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = cls(*args, **kwargs)
        obj.__class__ = Special
        return obj


class Special(Base):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Special, self).__init__(name)

    def rhyme(self):
        return 'Hi %s! How are you? Fine, thanks. What about you?' % self.name


>>> s = Base.alt_constructor("test")
>>> print s.rhyme()
Hi test! How are you? Fine, thanks. What about you?
```

**EDIT:**

Moved the constructor from `Special` to `Base`.

If you can't modify the `Base` class you can add a classmethod to `Special` that will change the class of any object passed to it.

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def greet(self):
        return 'Hello %s' % self.name


class Special(Base):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Special, self).__init__(name)

    def rhyme(self):
        return 'Hi %s! How are you? Fine, thanks. What about you?' % self.name

    @classmethod
    def convert_to_special(cls, obj):
        obj.__class__ = Special

>>> b = Base("test")
>>> print type(b)
<class '__main__.Base'>

>>> Special.convert_to_special(b)
>>> print type(b)
<class '__main__.Special'>
```

A more all purpose solution would be to create a mixin that can be added to any class.

```
class ConverterMixin(object):

    @classmethod
    def convert_to_class(cls, obj):
        obj.__class__ = cls


class Special(ConverterMixin, Base):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Special, self).__init__(name)

    def rhyme(self):
        return 'Hi %s! How are you? Fine, thanks. What about you?' % self.name

>>> b = Base("test")
>>> print type(b)
<class '__main__.Base'>

>>> Special.convert_to_class(b)
>>> print type(b)
<class '__main__.Special'>
```

Comment: @miku You're right, in my original answer I added an alternate constructor to `Base`, changing the way that class behaved. I've updated my answer with what I believe you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your update. Using `__class__` is an order of magnitude faster, which is not surprising, since in won't create a new object.

Answer (score 2):

actually you can, but I don't think you should. instead of typecasting python has duck-typing to solve this kind of situation.

anyway, here's the code:

```
>>> base = Base("I'm a base!")
>>> hasattr(base, 'rhyme')
False
>>> base.__class__ = Special
>>> hasattr(base, 'rhyme')
True
>>> base.rhyme()
"Hi I'm a base!! How are you? Fine, thanks. What about you?"
```