# Add attribute to object of dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, dataset, pytorch-geometric

I am very new to pytorch and pytorch-geometric. I need to load a dataset and then map an attribute to every object of the set that I will use later in the script. However I can't figure out how to do it.

I start the loading as

```
from torch_geometric.datasets import TUDataset

dataset = TUDataset(root='data/TUDataset', name='PROTEINS')
```

then I add the attribute. I tried (the value 3 is only for example, it will be a db query)

```
for data in dataset:
    data.keys.append('szemeredi_id')
    data.szemeredi_id = 3
```

or

```
for data in dataset:
    data['szemeredi_id'] = 3
```

or

```
for i, s in enumerate(dataset):
    dataset[i]['szemeredi_id'] = 3
```

or

```
for data in dataset:
    setattr(data, 'szemeredi_id', 3)
```

but that attribute is always empty. I even tried to write a decorator class for the Data class as

```
class SzeData(Data):
    def __init__(self, x=None, edge_index=None, edge_attr=None, y=None,
                 pos=None, normal=None, face=None, **kwargs):
        super(SzeData, self).__init__(x, edge_index, edge_attr, y, pos, normal, face)
        self.szemeredi_id = None
```

but if I try to replace the Data objects it raises the error `TypeError: 'TUDataset' object does not support item assignment` or it does nothing if I use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18020180/8160995).

Any suggestion is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: "that attribute is always empty": how do you access it?

Comment: I access it like `dataset[0]['szemeredi_id']` or with the `for data in dataset: data['szemeredi_id']`. If I try with the correspondent `.szemeredi_id` it says that the attribute doesn't exist

Comment: That won't work. `data` is a [new object](https://github.com/rusty1s/pytorch_geometric/blob/master/torch_geometric/data/in_memory_dataset.py#L69) and any assignment will only changes its local content. Your title is different from what you're trying on the text. Do you want to add an attribute to each sample (`data`) or one attribute to the dataset's object (`dataset`) as a whole?

Comment: I want to add the attribute to each sample `data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can organize your modification process to each sample `data` as a transform function, and then pass it to the `transform` or `pre_transform`(which depends on your need) parameter when constructing the dataset:

```py
from torch_geometric.datasets import TUDataset

def transform(data):
    data.szemeredi_id = 3
    return data

dataset = TUDataset(root='data/TUDataset', name='PROTEINS', transform=transform)
# or dataset = TUDataset(root='data/TUDataset', name='PROTEINS', pre_transform=transform)
```

See [the documentation of `torch_geometric.data.Dataset`](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/torch_geometric.data.Dataset.html)

> - **transform** (callable, optional) – A function/transform that takes in an `Data` object and returns a transformed version. The data object will be transformed before every access. (default: `None`)
> - **pre_transform** (callable, optional) – A function/transform that takes in an `Data` object and returns a transformed version. The data object will be transformed before being saved to disk. (default: `None`)

---

**Edit:**

The above method is unaware of the `data` index in the `dataset`, so if you want to add some index-related attributes, it won't help.

To add an index-related attribute (e.g. simply `index`), I use the less elegant but more general approach as follows:

```py
from torch_geometric.datasets import TUDataset

dataset = TUDataset(root='data/TUDataset', name='PROTEINS')

def add_attributes(dataset):
    data_list = []
    for i, data in enumerate(dataset):
        data.index = i
        data_list.append(data)
    dataset.data, dataset.slices = dataset.collate(data_list)
    return dataset

dataset = add_attributes(dataset)
```