# torch_geometric attach dataset tensor attribute to its graph data elements

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-geometric

I am working with the *ZINC* dataset from the `torch_geometric` library. I have managed to attach an extra attribute to it using the *put_tensor* function:

`dataset.put_tensor(wis, "wiener")`

where `wis` is an `int` tensor of length 10000 containing the Wiener indices for each graph in the dataset.

When I access the dataset `data` object

`dataset.data`

I get the following:

> `Data(x=[231664, 1], edge_index=[2, 498558], edge_attr=[498558], y=[10000], wiener=[10000])`

But, when I try to access the graphs individually, say, the first one, using the `get` method,

`dataset.get(0)`

the *wiener index* parameter does not show up anymore:

> `Data(x=[29, 1], edge_index=[2, 64], edge_attr=[64], y=[1])`

How can I attach the *wiener index* tensor value to each graph individually using the one stored in the `dataset` object?

Comment: relative: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64393072/add-attribute-to-object-of-dataset