# Override __hash__ in python dict mypy error

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, typeerror, mypy

I am writing a class that represents a hashable dictionary in Python, following what has been suggested in here: [hashable dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151658/python-hashable-dicts). I am doing this because I need it to be hashable for other implementations.

So I basically created my nice `HashableDict` class:

```
class HashableBinnerDict(dict[KEY, VALUE]):
    """
    Class that represents a hashable dict.
    """

    def __hash__(self) -> int:
        return hash(frozenset(self))
```

It inherits from dict and `KEY` and `VALUE` are two generic datatypes needed to parametrize the typing of my `HashableDict`.

The overall code that leverages such class works perfectly. However, mypy is complaining with this error:

```
error: Signature of "__hash__" incompatible with supertype "dict"  [override]
```

And I guess it is caused by the fact that inside the "base" class `dict` of python there's not implemented hash function, in fact we have (extracted from the dict class in the Python codebase):

```
class dict(object):
    ...
    ... # skipping non relevant code

    def __sizeof__(self): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__
        """ D.__sizeof__() -> size of D in memory, in bytes """
        pass

    __hash__ = None
```

The **hash** attribute is defined as None, so I guess mypy is complaining because of that. Any idea how to solve this besides brutally ignoring the error?

Comment: May I ask, why `def __hash__(self) -> Any`? `hash` is supposed to return an integer. Answer to your main question - no, you cannot, because parent class has `__hash__ = None` explicitly declared, and you assign a callable instead. It is definitely not a type problem, because nobody, I hope, will access `dict.__hash__` to get `None` (or will be punished for this weird thing) - so you can safely use an ignore comment.

Comment: (You're aware of bad consequences of hashable mutable containers, right?)

Comment: @SUTerliakov I am somewhat aware that this might not be the best practice, but if you can show me which could be the bad consequence, I would be more than happy :)

Comment: @SUTerliakov Yeah, the return type is a mistake of copy pasting, Im gonna fix it

Comment: The simplest bad consequence: https://gist.github.com/sterliakov/042bc5c3598217add267a5de497ba2b4

Comment: I understood! However, this hashable dict type I defined is going to be an attribute of a frozen dataclass (thus I supposed It would be basically not mutable). Does this somehow limit the problem? Is it ok in this case to use such hashing "trick" on the dictionary?

Comment: If it is supposed to be not mutable, I'd suggest to override `__setitem__`, `__delitem__`, `pop` and other modifying methods to raise an exception - this will help to avoid accidental mistakes. But yes, *immutable* hashable mapping is absolutely fine, like `tuple` vs `list`.

Comment: Interesting suggestions! If you want, you can add your comments as answer and I will accept it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end I found a better solution to my problem (thanks to my colleagues for the suggestion :D).

Implementing an hashable frozen dictionary is not a good idea, it is quite against the "core" of python.

There are some workarounds with `MappingProxyType` that allows you to generate a read only dictionary. However, `MappingProxyType` is not hashable and it is not possible to override / create the `__hash__` method because such class is marked as `final`.

Overriding by hand all the possible methods of base python classes is quite tricky and really prone to errors: it is enough to forget to override one method that changes the dictionary and you're done.

I found a workaround to ensure the hashability and immutability of my attribute while preserving the "usability" of a dictionary.

I created my attribute as `tuple[tuple[str, MyObject]]` and then I have a `cached_property` that converts such tuple in a dictionary that I can use.

So long story short: try to avoid weird overrides on python types to force a "non-intended" behaviour, change approach and be compliant with the python "philosophy"

Comment: **Nonsense.** Nothing could be more Pythonic than a `frozendict` builtin. After all, Python currently provides a comparable (and *much* less circumstantially useful) `frozenset` builtin. That Python lacks a `frozendict` is mostly just a historical accident. There have repeated attempts to standardize `frozendict` via the PEP process. Those attempts subjectively sucked and were thus abandoned. Nonetheless, a `frozendict` builtin is inevitable. It's only a matter of time until someone sufficiently **(A)** obsessive and **(B)** talented makes this happen, really.

Comment: It would be really appreciated if instead of telling to everyone they're saying bullshit you propose a working and reliable solution :) 

Frozendict is not available yet, so?

Answer (score -2):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2704866/8091093) answer provides an excellent `HashableDict` implementation:

```py
import collections

class FrozenDict(collections.Mapping):
    """Don't forget the docstrings!!"""
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._d = dict(*args, **kwargs)
        self._hash = None

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._d)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._d)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._d[key]

    def __hash__(self):
        if self._hash is None:
            hash_ = 0
            for pair in self.items():
                hash_ ^= hash(pair)
            self._hash = hash_
        return self._hash
```

Comment: That `__hash__()` implementation has absurd `O(n)` complexity. Caching it does *nothing* to obviate that complexity. Consider absurdly large dictionaries. You also do *nothing* to render the dictionary immutable.

Comment: @CecilCurry: Don't hashes of collection types necessarily have O(n) complexity?